# Unable to close the LCD Display Panel on an HP C3000 blade chassis

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-chassis

The LCD display panel at one of our HP C3000 blade chassis is stuck and I am unable to close it. See the image below. I am somewhat reluctant to push harder, as I am afraid that I might do additional damage to the chassis. Does anyone had a similar problem? Any options to resolve would be greatly appreciated.

[image: lcd display c3000]

Comment: I have to ask the dumb question first, have you pushed the side clips in all the way? Also is there anything inside the rack blocking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is silly...

How would anyone here know what's interfering with *your* [HP C3000 blade's](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/enclosures/product-detail.html?oid=3540808) display and its ability to retract into the enclosure?

If you're physically in front of the server, keep trying... but know that it's a [replaceable part](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01126895) using your warranty.

From the service manual, there isn't much that would block the travel path of the display. You may want to try to apply a bit more force (*withing reason*) or try to manually pull the device to make sure it's fully-extended before attempting to push it back again.

Otherwise, just break it :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was playing on the card that perhaps this might have happened to someone else :)

Comment: I've disassembled these before because of LCD burnout... but this seems like a question of what happened _right before_ you wrote this post? Had the LCD been stuck for a long time? Did it behave oddly prior?

Comment: Nothing much... The last time I used it (several months ago) it was working ..  my colleague called me and informed me that he was adding RAM to the blades.. after that he opened the LCD to view something and he was just unable close it afterwards .. His words were.. "I was adding memory into one of the servers... The LCD on the OA got stuck.. see if you can close it, you are more skillful in those things" :)